# Connecting serializers through a non primary key question

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm having trouble creating a relationship between Project and Token, i want to display all tokens for a project in the project json result. 
The PK of the project is stored in the project column in Token.

models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Token(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True)
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

serializers.py

```
class TokenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    allow_null=True
    class Meta:
        model = Token
        fields = ('id','symbol')

class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    development = DevelopmentSerializer()
    tokens = TokenSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('id','name','tokens')
```

The result i would like:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bitcoin",
    "tokens": [
        {
        "id": 1,
        "symbol": "BTC"
        }
    ]
}
```

At this time i get the following error:

Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `tokens` on serializer `ProjectSerializer`. The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Project` instance. Original exception text was: 'Project' object has no attribute 'tokens'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add a **related_name** to your **project** field on model **Token**, so it works as a revers look-up:

```
class Token(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, related_name='tokens')
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, now i get the following error: 

**Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `symbol` on serializer `TokenSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `RelatedManager` instance.
Original exception text was: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'symbol'.**

Comment: Found the problem. I had to add many=True to the TokenSerializer(). Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll appreciate you to select my answer